# How do you handle descriptive database table names and their effect on foreign key names?

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I am working on a database schema, and am trying to make some decisions about table names. I like at least somewhat descriptive names, but then when I use suggested foreign key naming conventions, the result seems to get ridiculous. Consider this example:

Suppose I have table

```
session_subject_mark_item_info
```

And it has a foreign key that references

```
sessionSubjectID
```

in the

```
session_subjects
```

table.

Now when I create the foreign key name based on fk_[referencing_table]__[referenced_table]_[field_name] I end up with this maddness:

```
fk_session_subject_mark_item_info__session_subjects_sessionSubjectID
```

**Would this type of a foreign key name cause me problems down the road, or is it quite common to see this?**

**Also, how do the more experienced database designers out there handle the conflict between descriptive naming for readability vs. the long names that result?**

I am using MySQL and MySQL Workbench if that makes any difference.

**UPDATE**

Received the answers I needed below, but I wanted to mention that after some testing, I discovered that MySQL does have a limit on how long the FK name can be. So using the naming convention I mentioned, and descriptive table names, meant that in two instances in my db I had to shorten the names to avoid the MySQL 1059 error

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-messages-server.html#error_er_too_long_ident

Comment: Oracle objects are limited to 30 character names, but MySQL has no such archaic limitations. If you were ever in the unfortunate situation of needing to move your application to Oracle, name length would be among the changes needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you care what the FK names are? You never see them in code or use them. We also name our tables quite descriptively and commonly have names like this, using SQL Server. It doesn't matter to us, because we never seen them. They are just there to enforce data.

Comment: +1, Name your tables well and forget about how long the FK names are! about the only time you ever see the FK name is when there is an error, and the long FK name is good then.

Comment: @Randy Minder: Well, when one is new to a topic, one doesn't know all the implications :) I wasn't sure if the FK names did get used elsewhere that would cause me trouble or coding problems later. Thanks for your "pointed" answer! I did discover since posting the question that MySQL has a limit on name length. One other question: does the name length affect DB performance in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

FK names are important for maintenance. Generally I only refernce the FK and the two table names, not the fields in the names. If you have named your fields correctly, it will be obvious what the fields are.

Comment: @HLGEM - thanks, I think you have provided insight to some of my other questions :) I was wondering about including the field names. I have named the fields the same in each table, so perhaps including that in the FK name is redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Although it probably makes no difference.  I will say that i've had table names both ways.  And in my opinion using long descriptive table names is overkill, and when working in code or even at the command line these long table names become burdensome and tedius.  I mean seriously, who in their right mind would have a nearly 30 character table name, ie.  stationchangelogmasterreport.  Now imagine tens or even hundreds of these in a database system.  from a developers point of view, this is just dumb!!  My recommendation...  put some thought into it, use abbreviations (when you can) and keep it short and to the point.  for example, the above table name could be shortened to:  stnchangelog, and if someone absolutely NEEDS a huge description explaining every meaning and use case for the table, then put this description in the table metadata, ie. the comments on the table.  This keeps us developers from going crazy (and hating you for it), and offers the "meaning" of the table if needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and being a developer myself I agree about trying to keep the table names as brief as possible. However the original question had to do with the naming convention for foreign keys, and there is a chance, even with relatively brief table and field names (however, I and never going to call a table "t" or a field "f" :) ) that these FK names can get long. It also becomes a potential issue when extending an existing db. Sometimes you have to play with the table names you're dealt.